# When i try to refresh the data from excel it gives me the error "IBM iSeries access ODBC driver [db2 udb] - Error message text unavailable

Tags: excel, database, odbc, pivot-table, driver

[shows this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfK5M.png)

When i try to refresh the data from excel it gives me the error

```
IBM iSeries access ODBC driver [db2 udb] - Error message text unavailable. Message cannot be translated successfully
```

try checking everything, all good
odbc drivers are installed and no issue

not sure what is causing this